# Timer countdown in product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, product-view, date

I want to display timer countdown in product view page.

how to achieve this ?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer) and [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/)

Comment: @MineshPatel Thanks for your valuable links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are in luck i am currently working on timer here is my code.

```
      <?php $end_datetime='your end date and time';
        $date =  date( "Y/m/d H:i:s",strtotime($end_datetime));   

        $endstr= date(strtotime($date));

        $nowstr = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
        $now =  date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $nowstr); ?>

          <span id="countdown" class"countdown">

            <script>getTimer('<?php echo $date?>','<?php echo $now ?>')</script>

            </span>
```

**js script**

```
function getTimer(dt,no)
{

 var end = new Date(dt);
 var now_date= new Date(no);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
      flag_time = true;
    timer = '';
    setInterval(function(){showRemaining();},1000);








    function showRemaining() 
    {
        var date = no;
                var now = new Date(date);
                var de= now.getTime();

                if ( flag_time ) {
                timer = de;
                }
                var d = new Date(timer);
                currentYear = d.getFullYear();
                month = d.getMonth()+1;

                var currentDate = d.getDate();
                currentDate = currentDate < 10 ? '0'+currentDate : currentDate;

                var hours = d.getHours();
                var minutes = d.getMinutes();
                var seconds = d.getSeconds();

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0'+seconds : seconds;
                var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes+ ':' + seconds; 
                timer = timer + 1000;
               var now_time = currentYear+'/' + month+'/' + currentDate + ' ' + strTime ;











        var now = new Date(now_time);


        var distance = end - now;

        if (distance < 0) {
             if (distance>-3) 
                {
                    location.reload(true); 
                    return;
                };

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Completed';


            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
       if (days <10)
        {days = '0' + days;}
    if (hours <10)
        {hours = '0' + hours;}
    if (minutes < 10)
       { minutes = '0' + minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10)
        {seconds = '0' + seconds; }
    if(days==00)
    {
                    dytext = '';   

    }
    else if(days==1)
    {
        dytext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ days +' Day  </span>';   
    }
    else
    {
         dytext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ days +' Days  </span>';    
    }
    if(hours==00) {
        hrtext='';
    }
    else {
        hrtext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ hours + '</span>'+ ":";
    }
    if(minutes==00)
    {
        mintext='';
    }else {
              mintext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ minutes +'</span>'+ ":";

    }
        sectext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ seconds +'</span>';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = dytext + hrtext +  mintext + sectext;
       flag_time = false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Is i required to replace my `attribute code` in your code ? or is any other changes i need to do ?

Comment: just add your end data and time in this variable  `$end_datetime='your end date and time';`

Comment: i addedd like this : `<?php $end_datetime='2016/06/10 12:15:15';` [here](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/butterfly-love-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html?SID=1it3ldo7vefbdterbh1kp9qgt1) click here 2nd time to open link

Comment: add js function too at the end of page

Comment: i already added, please check.

Comment: change function name in both places and clear ur cache

Comment: i replaced `getTimer` by `getTime` and  `showRemaining` by `showRemain` , cleared cache.

Comment: replace `getTimer` with `showtiming` in both no need to change other palces.

Comment: i changed as you said & removed other changes..

Comment: put space `<script> showtiming('<?php echo $date?>','<?php echo $now ?>') </script>`

Comment: i added the code.

Comment: seems its working, just a minute , i am checking

Comment: I wish you always work on same concepts that i work on :-)

Comment: Its displaying on all product-view page. but i need to display only for products that we set date and time for `attribute : ecomdev_expiry_date`

Comment: you have to add check if the product have that attribute then call this js function

Comment: please give me the code.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to show the counter in the product page, and it works fine. I set the same code to show the counter in the list of products for a specific category, but shows only the first product while others do not show them. Is there a solution to show the counter on all the products set?