# How To create countdown Timers in custom phtml

Tags: magento2, product, custom

I have two fields **StartDate** and **EndDate**.How to Implement **Timerfunctionality** with these fields in custom phtml

for example for the following format..

```
$startdate='31-10-22 00:00:00';
$enddate='01-11-22 00:00:00';
```

The timer will be like as '**00DAYS 24HOURS 00MINUTES 00SECONDS**'......

Comment: Please try this :

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158721/how-to-display-a-timer-countdown-from-a-static-block

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your template to show the Timer :

```
if ($timeer && $timeer->hasData()):
    $startTime = $timeer->getDisplayFrom() ? $timeer->getDisplayFrom() : '';
    $endTime = $banner->getDisplayTo() ? $timeer->getDisplayTo() : '';
    $start = $block->convertDateToTimeStamp($startTime);
    $end = $block->convertDateToTimeStamp($endTime);
    $now = $block->convertDateToTimeStamp();
    if ($start < $end && $now < $end):
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a substraction between end date and start date. Then you formate the result the way you want from the original timestamp.

The trick would be : if you want it to be dynamic, like seing the second moving. Then you need to plan some js/ jquery that will send an ajax request to retrieve dynamically the result of the substraction with the currrent timestamp. That being said i think it should be too heavy for the server to do that, I honestly don't know and never tried.

Comment: yes actullay i want like that the seconds moving.. so i don't know how to implement like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="startdate" value="2022-11-02 11:37:00"/>
<input type="hidden" id="enddate"   value="2022-11-05 18:00:00"/>
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

```
<script>
let endDate = document.getElementById("enddate").value;
    endDate = new Date(endDate).getTime();
let startDate =   document.getElementById("startdate").value;
    startDate = new Date(startDate).getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
   var now = new Date().getTime();
   var distance = -1;
    if (startDate <= now){
     distance = endDate - now;
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    }
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```